# Creating an overlap array with conditions - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

`Data = [day(1) day(2)...day(N)...day(2N)..day(K-N)...day(K)]`

I am looking to create a numpy array with two arrays, N and K with shapes (120,) and (300,). The array needs to be of the form:

`x1   = [day(1) day(2) day (3)...day(N)]
 x2   = [day(2) day(3)...day(N) day(N+1)]
 xN   = [day(N) day(N+1) day(N+2)...day(2N)]
 xK-N = [day(K-N) day(K-N+1)...day(K)]`

`X` is basically of shape (K-N)xN, with the above `x1,x2,...xK-N` as rows. I have tried using `iloc` for getting two arrays `N` and `K` with the same shapes. Good till then. But, when I try to merge the arrays using `X = np.array([np.concatenate((N[i:], K[:i] )) for i in range(len(N)])`, I am getting an `NxN` array in the form of an overlap array only, and not in the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to produce (with simpler data)?

```
In [253]: N,K=10,15
In [254]: data = np.arange(K)+10
In [255]: data
Out[255]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
In [256]: np.array([data[np.arange(N)+i] for i in range(K-N+1)])
Out[256]: 
array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

There's another way of generating this, using advanced ideas about `strides`:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data, shape=(K-N+1,N), strides=(4,4))
```

In the first case, all values in the new array are copies of the original.  The strided case is actually a view.  So any changes to `data` appear in the 2d array.  And without data copying, the 2nd is also faster.  I can try to explain it if you are interested.

---

`Warren` suggests using `hankel`.  That's a short function, which in our case does essentially:

```
a, b = np.ogrid[0:K-N+1, 0:N]
data[a+b]
```

`a+b` is an array like:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

In this example case it is just a bit better than the list comprehension solution, but I expect it will be a lot better for much larger cases.

Comment: Perfect, mate! That is exactly what I wanted, the first example that you provided. Thanks. I am interested in the strides concept too, it sounds interesting.

Comment: Instead of `strides=(4,4)`, it would be safer to use `strides=(data.stride[0],)*2`.  Even if you know the elements are integers, the size of each element is not necessarily 4 bytes.  On my computer, the default size of the items in an integer array is 8 bytes.  (And in "production code", you should carefully validate that `data` is, in fact, a 1-d array of sufficient length before using `as_strided`.)

Comment: Good point about the stride size.  I've added a solution based on what `hankel` does - which is probably the best non-striding solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not worth adding a dependence on scipy for the following, but if you are already using scipy in your code, you could use the function [`scipy.linalg.hankel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html):

```
In [75]: from scipy.linalg import hankel

In [76]: K = 16

In [77]: x = np.arange(K)

In [78]: x
Out[78]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

In [79]: N = 8

In [80]: hankel(x[:K-N+1], x[K-N:])
Out[80]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```